# Linq query using group by and having

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

So, I've been trying to replicate this `SQL` query:

```
select COUNT(*) as Total_2_Review
from (
    select processed_image_id, count(*) as Total_Confirm from dbo.history 
    where action_id=104
    group by processed_image_id
    having count(*) > 1
) as tbl
```

with `Linq` as follows:

```
var total2Review = (from h in secondDb.Histories.Where(i => i.ActionId == 104)
                    group h by new { h.ActionId, h.ProcessedImageId } into g
                    where g.Key.ActionId > 1
                    select g).Count();
```

However, I know it should not be right because I am not selecting the actual count greater to 1 in my group clause.

How can I accomplish this SQL query as a LINQ query?

Comment: Why are you grouping by `ActionId` in the Linq when you aren't in the SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `Key.ActionId` for `.Count()` in the `where` after the `group by`:

```
var total2Review = (from h in secondDb.Histories.Where(i => i.ActionId == 104)
                    group h by new { h.ActionId, h.ProcessedImageId } into g
                    where g.Count()> 1
                    select g).Count();
```

Answer (score 10):

LINQ makes no difference between `Where` and `Having`. An appropriate SQL query would be generated based on your placement of the `Where` clause.

Here is how I would translate your SQL query to LINQ:

```
var total2Review = secondDb.Histories
    .Where(i => i.ActionId == 104) // This "Where" remains a "where"
    .GroupBy(i => i.ProcessedImageId)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)     // This "Where" becomes "having"
    .Count();                      // This gets the overall count
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Can you help me how to get Count on a datefield? I have some student data with their exam dates. I wanna count the dates where the count is greater than two. Date field doesnt have a date.Count()?